# Get cookie of parent page (iframe) using JS

Tags: javascript, frontend

I need to get a cookie created in parent page.

[image]

I need get a spesific cookie (example) who was cread on modiface--locatelcolomia.myvtex.com and used this on my child page modiface.locatelcolobmia.com (this one is called by vtex iframe)

Comment: If the pages are in different domains, you can't access anything about one from the other.

Comment: If you have control over both sites use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add a login page using cookies. Don't do this. It is a huge security risk, and since there are extensions like EditThisCookie, people can login to other peoples' accounts. Instead, use [`$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, this is the answer: I got the cookie by Jquery and save on a input type hidden at the end send to my iframe calling a php page and send this value by URL (GET).

jQUERY

`let cartId = $('#idCartInput').val();`

IFRAME

```
("#idCartBtn").html("<iframe src='http://localhost:81/projectExample/modiface/index.php?cartId="+cartId+"' class='frameModiface' id='pruebasId' allow='camera' name='iframe_a'></iframe>");
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information, this section is for actual answers only

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly get cookies from other pages.

You can send a request to that page to send the cookies.

**getCookies.php** (put on parent page)

```js
window.onload = function(){document.getElementById('submitpost').submit();}
```

```html
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['COOKIE_NAME_HERE']) {die('set cookie');} ?>

<h3>Please wait</h3>

<form id="submitpost" action="PUT_PREVIOUS_PAGE_URL_HERE" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cookie" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['COOKIE_NAME_HERE']; ?>">
</form>
```

Then set the cookie to that.
Redirect users without the set cookie to the getCookies.php page.

This form can be intercepted and changed, but cookies can as well. Never put account details in cookies.

**This answer requires a web server with PHP, chances are that your host does support PHP.**